# Mailing form sends double copies to server

Tags: php, email

I have made a mailing form in php and all of a sudden (late night programming :) it started sending double messages to server side. After validating input fields, domain and mx records, it prepares the mail in the function below. I am using the "getMX-function" unaltered in other places with no problem, so I've concluded that the fault must be here somewhere, but I'm staring blind at it now.. I'm stuck!

When a visitors mail is successfully sent to server (email@website.com), server will send a response email to the visitor, to tell him server got his message. At one point both the visitor and server got double copies, but somehow I've seemingly fixed the visitor part of it... Don't ask me how, it was 5.30 in the morning and things where blurry. Server keeps on getting double copies though and as I said, I'm staring blind at it now.

I was hoping that someone else could point out an obvious fault in the code below, or maybe come to the conclusion that I should seek elsewhere. I have altered this code from it's previous version, to make it work with a bootstrap webpage and that's when the problem started.

Thanks!

```
<?

if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    $verification=$_POST['keystring'];
    if($verification==$_SESSION['keystring']){
        sendMail($_POST['cname'],$_POST['cmail'],$ctext,$contact);
        unset($_POST['send']);
    }else{
        print("<div class=\"col-sm-12 error\">Error message</div>");
    }
}

@set_time_limit(0);

function sendMail($client_name,$client_email,$client_message,$contact){
    if(checkFields($client_name,$client_email,$client_message)!=true){
        print($error);
    }else{
        $client_message=rtrim($client_message,"\n");
        if(isset($contact)){
            $server_email=$contact;
            $server_sender=$contact;
        }else{
            $server_email="email@website.com";
            $server_sender="email@website.com";
        }
        $server_name="website.com";
        $server_subject="Mailform response message";
        $server_headers="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
            "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n".
            "From: \"$client_name\" <".$client_email.">\r\n".
            "To: \"$server_name\" <".$server_email.">\r\n".
            "Date: ".date("r")."\r\n".
            "Subject: ".$server_subject."\r\n";
        $server_message="<html>\r\n".
            "<body>\r\n".
            "<h4>$client_name - $client_email</h4>\r\n".
            "<h4>$client_message</h4>\r\n".
            "<h4> Origin: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']." </h4>\r\n".
            "</body>\r\n".
            "</html>\r\n";
        $server_response=getMX($server_email,$server_subject,$server_message,$client_email,$server_headers);
        if($server_response[0]){
            print("<div class=\"col-sm-12\"><h4 class=\"success\">Success message server</h4>".$server_response[1]."</div>\n");
            $client_headers="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
                "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n".
                "From: \"$server_name\" <".$server_sender.">\r\n".
                "To: \"$client_name\" <".$client_email.">\r\n".
                "Date: ".date("r")."\r\n".
                "Subject: ".$server_subject."\r\n";
            $server_message="<html>\r\n".
                "<body>\r\n".
                "<h4>Thank you for visiting our website!</h4>\r\n".
                "<h4>We will get back to you as soon as possible</h4>\r\n".
                "</body>\r\n".
                "</html>\r\n";
            $client_response=getMX($client_email,$server_subject,$server_message,$server_sender,$client_headers);
            if($client_response[0]){
                print("<div class=\"col-sm-12\"><h4 class=\"confirm\">Confirmation response was sent</h4>".$client_response[1]."</div>\n");
            }else{
                print("<div class=\"col-sm-12\"><h4 class=\"error\">Confirmation response was not sent</h4>".$client_response[1]."</div>\n");
            }
            unset($_POST['cname']);
            unset($_POST['cmail']);
            unset($_POST['ctext']);
        }else{
            print("<div class=\"col-sm-12\"><h4 class=\"success\">Success message client</h4><br />".$server_response[1]."</div>\n");
            unset($_POST['cname']);
            unset($_POST['cmail']);
            unset($_POST['ctext']);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

The html form is generated as follows:

```
<?

$imgverify="?".session_name()."=".session_id();
$html="<div class=\"col-sm-12\">\n";
    $html.="<h3>Kontakt</h3>\n";
    $html.="Send us a mail :)<br /><br />";
    $html.="<div class=\"mailform\" id=\"mailform\">\n"; // added "id=mailform" for centerScroll javascript function.
        $html.="<form role=\"form\" action=\"#mailform\" method=\"post\">\n"; // added "action=#mailform" for centerScroll javascript function.
            $html.="<div class=\"form-group\">\n";
                $html.="<label for=\"cname\">Name</label>\n";
                $html.="<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"cname\" name=\"cname\" placeholder=\"Enter name\" value=\"".$_POST['cname']."\">\n";
            $html.="</div>\n";
            $html.="<div class=\"form-group\">\n";
                $html.="<label for=\"cmail\">Email</label>\n";
                $html.="<input type=\"email\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"cmail\" name=\"cmail\" placeholder=\"Enter email address\" value=\"".$_POST['cmail']."\">\n";
            $html.="</div>\n";
            $html.="<div class=\"form-group\">\n";
                $html.="<label for=\"ctext\">Message</label>\n";
                $html.="<textarea class=\"form-control\" rows=\"5\" id=\"ctext\" name=\"ctext\" placeholder=\"Enter message\">".$_POST['ctext']."</textarea>\n";
            $html.="</div>\n";
            $html.="<div class=\"form-group\">\n";
                $html.="<label for=\"imgver\">Fill in the code before sending</label>\n";
                $html.="<table>\n<tr>\n";
                    $html.="<td style=\"width:100%;\">\n";
                        $html.="<div><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"keystring\" name=\"keystring\" placeholder=\"Enter code\"></div>\n";
                        $html.="<div><input class=\"btn btn-default\" type=\"submit\" name=\"send\" value=\"Send\" style=\"width:100%;margin-top:5px;\"></div>\n";
                        $html.="<div><input class=\"btn btn-default\" type=\"submit\" name=\"updatecode\" value=\"Update code\" style=\"width:100%;margin-top:5px;\"></div>\n";
                    $html.="</td>\n<td>\n";
                        $html.="<div id=\"imgver\" style=\"margin-left:10px;\"><img style=\"\" src=\"include/image.verification/index.php".$imgverify."\" alt=\"\" /></div>\n";
                    $html.="</td>\n";
                $html.="</tr>\n</table>\n";
            $html.="</div>\n";
        $html.="</form>\n";
    $html.="</div>\n";
$html.="</div>\n";
print($html);

?>
```

Edit:

Apparently I need 10 reputation to post images and since I made this account 12 hours ago...

A screenshot of the form after a mail has been sent is here:
http://nocode.se/mailform.jpg
It's in swedish and the green text says "The message has been sent". The blue text says "A confirmation has been sent to you". The lines under these texts are the respective mail servers response, that is mine and the visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you check this lines:

```
$server_response=getMX($server_email,$server_subject,$server_message,$client_email,$server_headers);
if($server_response[0]){
```

At the end of that if you send another email.

Comment: The script is supposed to send two emails, one to the server and if this is successful one to the visitor too.. I'm guessing you refer to the line where it says "$client_response..."?